# Java Vector without re-ordering indices on remove, but leaving them null reusing those spaces on add command

Tags: java, arrays, list, vector, indices

I want to avoid using plain arrays for this because I want something that has atleast the following commands

```
//grows in size if no null's are found.
key = indexOf(value);<br>
remove(key);<br>
add(value);<br>
contains(value);<br>
length(); //size();
```

Vector has all this except for the part of keeping the order of the indices in tact.

Maybe what I want already exists in Java SDK? Can someone tell me what it's called.

Code:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class VectorDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // create an empty Vector vec with an initial capacity of 4      
      Vector<Integer> vec = new Vector<Integer>(4);

      // use add() method to add elements in the vector
      vec.add(0,111);
      vec.add(1,9999);
      vec.add(2,191919);
      vec.add(3,-12394);

     System.out.println(vec);
     vec.remove(2);
     System.out.println(vec);

   }  
}
```

Output:

```
Executing the program....
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M VectorDemo 
[111, 9999, 191919, -12394]
[111, 9999, -12394]
```

While I wanted this one output..

Output:

```
[111, 9999, 191919, -12394]
[111, 9999, null,   -12394]
```

Comment: Why is this what you need? What are you going to use this data structure for?

Comment: When I remove a player from my game. I don't want all the players to move around since they use the `indexOf` I want a empty seat instead then fill it with another player later.

Comment: Don't use java.util.Vector. `If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.`

Comment: What are these flags used for? -Xmx128M -Xms16M

Comment: @MonaJalal those flags just limit the Java Virtual Machine (java.exe) from taking too much RAM it limits it. Xmx is MAX RAM Memory to use. Xms is the least RAM MEMORY. so the JAVA.exe will be 16 MB at start up and can grow up to 128 MB.. usually I use this command for VPS servers where you get limited amount of RAM. You can use `m` for MB `k` for KB `g` for GB. But these flags can still crash your program when it needs more RAM then you give it. then it may give OutOfMemoryExecption error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use

```
vec.set(2, null);
```

to reuse null elements on add you can do this

```
   int i = vec.indexOf(null)
   if (i == -1) {
        vec.add(obj);
   } else {
        vec.set(i, obj);
   }
```

Comment: This isn't that bad. I guess I'll do it like this.